# Why can't subclasses create new objects with a base class protected constructor?

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor, protected

I'm porting some Java code to C#, and I ran into this idiom used to copy objects:

```
class Base
{
    int x;
    public Base(int x) { this.x = x; }
    protected Base(Base other) { x = other.x; }
}

class Derived : Base
{
    Base foo;
    public Derived(Derived other)
        : base(other)
    {
        foo = new Base(other.foo); // Error CS1540
    }
}
```

**Error CS1540 being:**

> Cannot access protected member 'Base.Base(Base)' via a qualifier of type 'Base'; the qualifier must be of type 'Derived' (or derived from it)

I understand the purpose of this error: it prevents accessing protected members of sibling types. But Base.Base(Base) is obviously not going to be invoked on a sibling type! Is this simply not included in the spec, or am I missing some reason why this would not be safe?

EDIT: Gah, the idiom was `new Base(other.foo)` not `new Base(other)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its not accessible you can check this post for details : [Many Questions: Protected Constructors](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/peterhal/archive/2005/06/29/434070.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the link, so protected constructors are blocked... as a security protection? That's weird.

Comment: yeah........even i dont know about this but after reading this i saw other side of coin

Comment: Marking as answer because it links the reasoning. Would be nice if someone (with more time than me!) edited the reasoning in to this answer for others.

Comment: The link is dead - I tried on Web Archive too: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/peterhal/434070.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Sections 3.5.2 and 3.5.3 of the language specification spell this out, I'll post 3.5.2 for convenience (it's shorter!) and let you find 3.5.3 on your own.

> In intuitive terms, when a type or
>   member M is accessed, the following
>   steps are evaluated to ensure that the
>   access is permitted:
>
> - First, if M is declared within a type (as opposed to a compilation unit
>     or a namespace), a compile-time error
>     occurs if that type is not accessible.
> - Then, if M is public, the access is permitted.
> - Otherwise, if M is protected internal, the access is permitted if
>     it occurs within the program in which
>     M is declared, or if it occurs within
>     a class derived from the class in
>     which M is declared and takes place
>     through the derived class type
>     (§3.5.3).
> - **Otherwise, if M is protected, the access is permitted if it occurs
>     within the class in which M is
>     declared, or if it occurs within a
>     class derived from the class in which
>     M is declared and takes place through
>     the derived class type (§3.5.3).**
> - Otherwise, if M is internal, the access is permitted if it occurs
>     within the program in which M is
>     declared.
> - Otherwise, if M is private, the access is permitted if it occurs
>     within the type in which M is
>     declared.
> - Otherwise, the type or member is inaccessible, and a compile-time error
>     occurs.

Basically, access to protected members of the base have to be through instances of the derived. As you said, siblings cannot access each others' protected members, but the language specification also prohibits children from accessing protected members of the base unless the reference is through the child.

Comment: Sure, I get that for non constructor members, but as far as I know, constructor members are only invoked by the implementation of `new` - so I can't see how this could be un-typesafe.

Comment: @Simon, I will not try to pretend I could think of the corner cases where this could blow up but I don't doubt for a second *somebody* could figure something out. I can only say you can work around the limitation by providing a protected method instead of a protected constructor. `protected Base CreateBase(Base other)` which can be called via the derived child.

Comment: @Simon: Want to call a `protected` constructor in any library?  Just write ten lines of code!  That's why it's illegal.

Comment: @Rick: My interpretation of `protected` is it is there to help enforce typesafety and making enforcing Liskov substitutability easier, if I want to prevent other assemblies from accessing a member for security, I would think of `internal` or `private`. If that's not the intended use, then that's my answer!

Comment: @Simon: Yes, those are other accessibility solutions for other problems.  But `protected` members are specifically intended to be callable from derived classes in other assemblies (but only if the instance **is** actually derived).  Neither `private` nor `internal` applies to that use case.

Comment: @Rick: In that case, what is the security difference between being able to construct `Base` and being able to construct `class MyBase : Base {}`? What can you do with `Base` that you can't do with `MyBase`?

Comment: @Simon Buchan: For one thing, it's possible to have a protected constructor accept parameters of protected types.  For another, it's possible that a particular base class constructor would be unable, by itself, to establish necessary invariants for the class.  It's clearly not possible for a base class constructor to guarantee that all constructed instances of derived classes will be usable, but if an instance constructed with a certain base-class constructor would be guaranteed unusable, why allow its construction?

Comment: @supercat: These are reasons for protected constructors, not for disallowing derived classes from calling protected constructors in other ways than `base()`.

Comment: @Simon Buchan: The purpose of declaring a constructor protected isn't so much to restrict who can create instances, but rather what sorts of instances can be created.  Declaring a class "foo" constructor "protected" prevents it from being used to create instances of "foo", while allowing it to be used in the creation of types derived from "foo".  Calling any constructor of "foo" by any means other than chaining from a derived class constructor would yield an instance of "foo", rather than an instance of a derived class--precisely what the "protected" declaration is supposed to prevent.

Comment: @Simon Buchan: If one wanted to prevent a particular constructor from being used to create derived classes, one could make it "private", and expose a public or protected static factory method to invoke it.  Note that while it's legal to declare static methods as "protected", any code which is allowed to inherit a class would be allowed to define a sham derived class, whose purpose was simply to invoke the protected members.  If one wants to prevent code outside the assembly from accessing access certain static members, the best way is to declare those members "internal".

Comment: @supercat: Yes, I do understand how access specifiers work, thank you :). So how would you translate the idiom in the original post in a way that isn't obviously working around the language preventing something that is perfectly safe from both a memory and design viewpoint?

Comment: @Simon Buchan: Define a static protected factory method.

Answer (score 4):

I you **could** do this, then you could **always** trivially invoke `protected` members of any class that allowed you to derive from it, even though the derived class is not used.  This totally subverts the security of the `protected` mechanism.

For example, let's say we derive from `Base` with `Derived` as above.  If the rules weren't as they are, you could add a method like this to `Derived`:

```
public static void CallProtectedMethod(Base baseInstance)
{
    baseInstance.ProtectedMethod();
}
```

and now anyone can invoke it like this:

```
Derived.CallProtectedMethod(baseInstance);
```

while the direct approach fails:

```
baseInstance.ProtectedMethod();
```

In this case `baseInstance` might really be of type `Base` and have nothing to do with `Derived`.  To prevent this and ensure that `protected` methods stay `protected` unless the instance really is of the `Derived` type, calling these methods through a different instance is illegal.

Likewise for `protected` constructors:

```
public static Base CreateProtectedBase()
{
    return new Base();
}
```

and now anyone can invoke it like this:

```
var baseInstance = Derived.CreateProtectedBase();
```

while the direct approach fails:

```
var baseInstance = new Base();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you create a new object of base in derived you cannot access the protected members through that object.
try this code

```
class Base
{
     protected int x;
}
class Derived : Base
{
    Base foo;
    void testMethod()
    {
        base.x = 5;
        foo.X = 5;// this throws an error 
    }
}
```

Change access specifier of the constructor to make it work or instead of creating a object of base class(Base) use `base.X`